# Response.Write function not working when I pass the main function throught Jquery.post()

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, http-post

I have a function ExportToExcel that exports html Data to excel using response.write. I run this function on button click using jquery method post.

```
function ExportToExcel() {
    ShowNotification('Exporting to Excel', false);
    $.post(exportUrl, null, function (jsonresponse) {
        HideNotification();
    });
```

problem is if use post method the excel file is not downloaded. if i use this function without running it through Jquery it runs fine and downloads the file. am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to use jquery in that case.
Just use a link or post a form.

Search for "download pdf jquery .post" and you find a lot of explanations and alternative solutions.

Comment: I need Jquery for the loading notification while the file is downloading that is why i can't use it alone :s

Comment: try this one: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery-plugin-for-requesting-ajax-like-file-downloads.html